# How to calculate a meaningful distance between multidimensional tensors

Tags: features, feature-extraction, metric, anomaly-detection, tensor

**TLDR**: given two tensors $t_1$ and $t_2$, both with shape $(c,h,w),$ how shall the distance between them be measured?

---

**More Info**: I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to distinguish between an anomalous sample (specifically from `MNIST`) and a "regular" sample (specifically from `CIFAR10`). The solution I chose is to consider the feature maps that are given by `ResNet` and use *kNN*. More specifically:

- I embed the entire `CIFAR10_TRAIN` data to achieve a dataset that consists of activations with dimension $(N,c,h,w)$ where $N$ is the size of `CIFAR_TRAIN`
- I embed $2$ new test samples $t_C$ and $t_M$ from `CIFAR10_TEST` and `MNIST_TEST` respectively (both with shape $(c,h,w)$), same as I did with the training data.
- (**!**) I find the *k-Nearest-Neighbours* of $t_C$ and $t_M$ w.r.t the embedding of the training data
- I calculate the mean distance between the $k$ neighbors
- Given some predefined threshold, I classify $t_C$ and $t_M$ as regular or anomalous, hoping that the distance for $t_M$ would be higher, as it represents O.O.D sample.

Notice that in (**!**) I need some distance measure, but this is not trivial as these are tensors, not vectors.

---

**What I've Tried**: a trivial solution is to flatten the tensor to have shape $(c\cdot h\cdot w)$ and then use basic $\ell_2$, but the results turned out pretty bad. (could not distinguish regular vs anomalous in this case). Hence: *Is there a better way of measuring this distance*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an [earth mover distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) in 2d  or 3d over the image? For example you could follow [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/implementation-of-squared-earth-movers-distance-loss-function-for-ordinal-scale/107927/2) example, but call it sequentially. The idea would be something like the following (untested and written on my cell phone):

```
def cumsum_3d(a):
    a = torch.cumsum(a, -1)
    a = torch.cumsum(a, -2)
    a = torch.cumsum(a, -3)
    return a

def norm_3d(a):
    return a / torch.sum(a, dim=(-1,-2,-3), keepdim=True)

def emd_3d(a, b):
    a = norm_3d(a)
    b = norm_3d(b)
    return torch.mean(torch.square(cumsum_3d(a) - cumsum_3d(b)), dim=(-1,-2,-3))
```

This should also work with batched data. I would also try normalizing the images first (so they each sum to 1) unless you want to account for changes in intensity.

Comment: can this function be used within torch.cdist, to account for pairwise distances of every pair?

Comment: It looks like torch.cdist only supports different values of p for the L_p distance. It doesn’t look like it supports applying a function to all pairs. Sounds like you want to make a kernel matrix? You could use something like https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.combinations.html and then stack the 0,1 elements from the tuples into two tensors, then run this?

Comment: Or better you could flatten after doing the 3d cumsum in the example above. Then you could use cdist with p=2 to replace the subtract and square steps. You would give the function your list of per-sample flattened cumsum tensors (samples x flat) twice. Then that would be all pairwise distances with something kind of like an EMD.

Comment: Wow, this has worked tremendously well. I highly appreciate your response.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help.

Comment: You could do the same process using torch.cdist and the embedding output (before classification layer) of a ResNET or whatever pretrained/frozen image model. You might want to divide each embedded vector by its norm first though so you have a cosine similarity rather than a pure l2 if you do that though. Embeddings from a good image model should be better than emd, but I bet emd is a pretty good baseline.